# How to use having condition in SQL query

Tags: sql, case, having

```
SELECT 
    userid,
    CASE 
       WHEN (COUNT(CASE  
                      WHEN onlinesportsgamewagers != 0
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE null
                   END)  
             + COUNT(CASE 
                        WHEN depositmade_amt != 0
                           THEN 1
                           ELSE null
                     END)) >= 10  
            THEN "VIP"
            ELSE "NON-VIP"
    END as VIPcheck             
FROM 
    player_activity
WHERE 
    userid = 2023410 
GROUP BY 
    year(txndate), month(txndate)
```

This query determines the user's VIP status for each month.

Ultimately, I want to have a query that determines if the user achieved VIP status for at least 3 months (including the current month). For the time being, it's only user 2023410, but eventually I want to run this for the whole database.

Therefore my ultimate output would be:

User                          -   VIPcheck (3 different months w/ active status)

(one row per userID)

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN onlinesportsgamewagers != 0
            THEN 1
                ELSE null
            END)  
                + COUNT(CASE WHEN depositmade_amt != 0
                        THEN 1
                            ELSE null
                        END)) >= 10  
            THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END)
```

Tried the above having statement, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this gets the VIP status for one user by month:

```
SELECT userid, year(txndate), month(txndate),                                                                                         
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN onlinesportsgamewagers <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                  SUM(CASE WHEN depositmade_amt <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 10
             THEN 'VIP'
             ELSE 'NON-VIP'
        END) as VIPcheck             
FROM player_activity
GROUP BY userid, year(txndate), month(txndate);
```

Another aggregation will get what you want:

```
SELECT userid,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(VIPcheck = 'VIP') >= 3 THEN 'SUPER-VIP'
             WHEN SUM(VIPcheck = 'VIP') >= 1 THEN 'VIP'
             ELSE 'HOI POLLOI'
        END) as status
FROM (SELECT userid, year(txndate), month(txndate),                                                                                         
             (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN onlinesportsgamewagers <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                        SUM(CASE WHEN depositmade_amt <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 10
                   THEN 'VIP'
                   ELSE 'NON-VIP'
              END) as VIPcheck             
      FROM player_activity
      GROUP BY userid, year(txndate), month(txndate)
     ) uym
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: Hi. your query seemed to work. However, i don't understand why one would put the [VIP status for one user by month] in the FROM section rather than the SELECT section?

Comment: @eddd83 . . . I don't fully understand the comment, but this query needs to do two aggregations.  Hence, there is a subquery in the `FROM` clause.